# Aborting a library operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, abort

I'm using a 3rd party library, which has a method:

```
secureSend(int channel, byte[] data);
```

This method sends my binary data to the library, and if the data is larger than 64K, the method splits it to 64K chunks and sends them in order.

This method is marked as blocking, so it won't return immediately. Therefore is also advised to spawn a thread for each usage of this function:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        library.secureSend(channel, mydata);
    }
}).start();
```

If I'm trying to send larger data (>1Mb), it will take about 30 seconds. This is fine.

However sometimes I need to interrupt the sending because there is a higher priority data to send.

Currently, If I spawn a new thread with calling `secureSend` it will have to wait, as library operates in FIFO-manner, ie.: it will finish first with previous sendings.

I decompiled the library's class files, and `secureSend` has the following pseudo algorithm:

```
public synchronized void secureSend(int c, byte[] data) {
    try {
        local_data = data;
        HAS_MORE_DATA_TO_SEND = (local_data.length > 0)
    
        while (HAS_MORE_DATA_TO_SEND) {
            HAS_MORE_DATA_TO_SEND = sendChunk(...); //calculates offset, and length, and returns if still has more, operates with local_data!
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {}
}
```

I've tried to interrupt the thread (I've stored it), but it didn't helped.

The library spends a lot of time in that `while` loop. However, it also fear of `IOException`.

**My question: can I anyhow interrupt/kill/abort this function call? Maybe somehow throwing an IOException into the Thread? Is this somewhat possible?**

Comment: If it doesn't handle interruption, then this isn't really possible.

Comment: It doesn't have anything similar to interruption, I can `close` the underlying media that will cause an IOExpception but in turn I'll lose the connection too and have to rebuild. Thanks for the comment anyway!